# Sublime Text 2 error installing package control - can not remove

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sublimetext2

After setting up Sublime Text 2, I tried to install package control but I faced an error. Then every time I open Sublime Text 2, there was an error :

```
Unable to run package setup:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 165, in upgrade
    upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir, datadir, backupdir)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 158, in upgradePackage
    os.path.join(backupdir, base), inhibitOverwrite)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 90, in upgradeArchive
    writeFile(fname, newar.read(f))
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 18, in writeFile
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fo: 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/halink/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Package Control/package_control/preferences_filename.py'
```

I tried to remove it and re-install but I cann't. Can anybody tell me how to fix it or how to remove Sublime Text and I can re-install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed instruction here :
http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907 and delete the desktop file I have created before. It worked now !

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because of 'Packages' folder permission.

You could run in your terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "/home/{yourself}/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/
```

also, you could need to set permission on some other folders.